# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCExcep tion: could not execute query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I have researched this in these forums thoroughly and many people have posted stuff but none of that helps me.

my object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByRegistrationId", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.registration_id = :registration_id")
public class Address {

@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long address_id;

@Column(name = "REGISTRATION_ID")
private long registration_id;

public long getRegistration_id() {
    return registration_id;
}

public void setRegistration_id(long registration_id) {
    this.registration_id = registration_id;
}
```

my repository implementation:

```
@Repository
public class AddressRepositoryJpa implements AddressRepository {
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AddressRepositoryJpa.class.getName());

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Address findByID(int id) {
    return entityManager.find(Address.class, id);
}

@Override
public Address findByRegistrationID(Long registration_id) {
    TypedQuery<Address> query = (TypedQuery<Address>) entityManager.createNamedQuery("Address.findByRegistrationId", Address.class);
    query.setParameter("registration_id", registration_id);
    Address address = (Address) query.getSingleResult();
    return address;
}
```

my persistence.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxx:1521/XXX.XXX.XXX.XX.XX"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <map><!--validate | update | create | create-drop-->
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.rmit.core.entities"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>
```

I have tried named queries and even one without parameters as a list and no luck, I wonder if there is any special configuration I need to do.

The entitymanager.find method works, so the connection to the db is fine.

Thanks a lot.

stacktrace:

```
Hibernate: select address0_.ADDRESS_ID as ADDRESS_ID1_0_, address0_.ADDRESS_1 as
 ADDRESS_2_0_, address0_.ADDRESS_2 as ADDRESS_3_0_, address0_.ADDRESS_3 as ADDRE
SS_4_0_, address0_.ADDRESS_TYPE as ADDRESS_TYPE5_0_, address0_.CITY as CITY6_0_,
 address0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY7_0_, address0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_BY8_0_, addre
ss0_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_ON9_0_, address0_.MODIFIED_BY as MODIFIED_BY10_0_, ad
dress0_.MODIFIED_ON as MODIFIED_ON11_0_, address0_.POSTCODE as POSTCODE12_0_, ad
dress0_.REGISTRATION_ID as REGISTRATION_ID13_0_, address0_.STATE as STATE14_0_,
address0_.STUDENT_ID as STUDENT_ID15_0_ from ADDRESS address0_ where address0_.R
EGISTRATION_ID=?
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCExcep
tion: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntit
yManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntit
yManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:5
24)
        at edu.rmit.core.repositories.jpa.AddressRepositoryJpa.findByRegistratio
nID(AddressRepositoryJpa.java:36)
        at edu.rmit.core.services.impl.AddressServiceImpl.findByRegistrationID(A
ddressServiceImpl.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflecti
on(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJo
inpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.
proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.
invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.in
voke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(
ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynami
cAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1621.findByRegistrationID(Unknown Source)
        at edu.rmit.rest.mvc.OrderSummaryController.getOrderSummaryMapByID(Order
SummaryController.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(
InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeF
orRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocabl
eHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapt
er.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpo
int.java:2522)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoin
t.java:2511)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.conver
t(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlException
Helper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2556)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslat
orImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.
java:231)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:4
95)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:
147)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getInt(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:
818)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.jav
a:928)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:434)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultS
et.java:283)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultS
et.java:283)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(I
ntegerTypeDescriptor.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtract
or.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStan
dardBasicType.java:267)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStan
dardBasicType.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStan
dardBasicType.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandard
BasicType.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(Abstra
ctEntityPersister.java:2969)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Lo
ader.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
        ... 64 more
```

Comment: There is some problem with the variable type, can you try search by address-id instead of registration-id. Lemme know.

Comment: Hi Borg, the value I have is the registration id, unfortunately, but is a Long, so maybe you have a point, not sure how to deal with it though.

Comment: Also please remove the jdbc dataSource url from the configuration you've shared, that should be considered sensitive information ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just a matter of improper casing :)

[Named Parameters in Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbtg/index.html)

> Named parameters are case-sensitive and may be used by both dynamic and static queries.

You can easily test it out by using this API instead
`javax.persistence.Query#setParameter(int, java.lang.Object)` like so:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("find address by registration_id");
query.setParameter(1, registration_id);
Address address = (Address) query.getSingleResult();
return address;
```

Comment: I have tried this, thanks, but I get the same problem, I was reading the exception though and maybe it is related to the fact that I am using a parameter defined in my entity as Long? I will post the section of the stack trace above so you see what I mean. If I were to try a different approach than named queries, what would you recommend?

Comment: Can you add a break point on the if clause of this method `org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader#checkQuery`, it's `org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader:500`? See which one of the two conditions triggers the `org.hibernate.QueryException`?

Comment: Maybe you should use `javax.persistence.EntityManager#createNamedQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<T>)` and update your code to also instruct it about the type of the query result you're expecting like this `TypedQuery<Address> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("find address by registration_id", Address.class);`. Since `javax.persistence.TypedQuery` interface extends the one you're already programming your query against `javax.persistence.Query` the rest of the code should compile...

Comment: Thanks a lot Filip, your answer made sense, I have made the changes as you can see in the edited post above to use typedQuery but pretty much get the same error, as for the break point for org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader I am not sure how to do that, can you please explain?

Comment: [Debugging java code in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: I see you've enabled `<entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` can you please share the SQL it outputs and also let us know if running the SQL against the database works? Cause you know, while the SQL keywords are case-insensitive in SQL the names of columns are not...

Comment: Hi Filip, the sql is already visible at the start of the stacktrace, I have grabbed that sql statement and ran it in my sqldeveloper and it works fine, remember I have also manage to get working other db retrieval using entitymanager.find method, so the connection to the database is fine.
I believe the problem is some configuration in hibernate that does not allow me to run namedqueries, maybe you can point me to a mistake in my persistence.xml?

Comment: regarding the debugging I know how to debug but not ho to attach the source and put a debugging point where you tell me (that hibernate class)

Comment: Also please have `Address` implement `java.io.Serializable`

> If an entity instance is to be passed by value as a detached object (e.g., through a remote interface), the entity class must implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: @Runnerdave the solution was just the serialization omission?

Comment: Hi Filip, no it was that I had another field called "student_id" defined as int in my entity but in the database it was a varchar!

Answer (score 3):

I have found what the problem was, in my entity I had another field called "student_id" that was defined in the entity as int but in the database is a varchar.

So the errors given where not related to the field I was focusing on: "registration_id" but to another one.

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

try naming your query like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByRegistrationId")...
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck, it is a good advice though, it looks better that way, thanks.

Comment: How are you giving the registration_id, are you using long? and just for clarification, you have getters/setters in your entity class right?